# ClassNotFoundException for dependencies on java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-management, classnotfoundexception

I want to get my PC specs with a java program. I'm trying to make use of Oshi library to get this done but I am having problems implementing the dependencies on my project

I want to simply run this

```java
SystemInfo systemInfo = new SystemInfo();
HardwareAbstractionLayer hardware = systemInfo.getHardware();
CentralProcessor processor = hardware.getProcessor();

System.out.println(processor.toString());
```

but I'm getting this error:
[image]

I have added these dependencies from this link: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.oshi/oshi-core/6.3.1/jar

Here is a picture of the Project Explorer
[Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm7gS.png)

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong with the dependencies, maybe I am not getting the proper dependencies but I want to know what is happening or exactly which jars I need to add to get Oshi running on my java project

Comment: The missing class `LoggerFactory` is in `slf4j-api-2.0.3.jar` so you aren't missing any dependency.  The issue seems to be that your dependencies aren't on your build path.
Did you refresh your project after adding these dependencies?  If not, that could be your solution

Comment: Now I changed  the dependencies in my build path, did refresh but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Something I would like to notice. When I hover my mouse on the imports, I'm getting the following message "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found"

Comment: Can you import the class `LoggerFactory` directly in your code without getting compilation errors?  If so, then your issue is only at runtime - how are you running your code and what is the CLASSPATH variable?
If you do get compilation errors, then the problem is likely the jar file itself.  I would redownload it and import it into eclipse again

Comment: You may have added them to your "Build Path" in eclipse (which is why you can compile) but they must be on your "Class Path" at run time.  Look for the `.classPath` file in your project root.  Go to the "Run Configurations" dialog (Run -> Run Configurations) for the class you are executing and click on "Dependencies" there.   To save yourself trouble in the future, use a dependency manager like Maven or Gradle that does this stuff for you automagically!

Comment: You were both right! The problem was in the classpath, it was completely empty! Now I added the dependencies in the classpath and now it seems that is working

Comment: @HansRicardoDavilaAcuña Eclipse can sometimes be picky that way.  Do yourself a favor and set up your project using Maven.  (Configure --> add Maven nature.). You can add dependencies in your pom.xml file and Eclipse/Maven takes care of all the classpath stuff.  (You would only need to add the oshi dependency, and its own pom tells Maven what other dependencies to get.). Your future self will thank you a million times over.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I did a test in gradle with Intellij IDEA and it was very easy to get Oshi dependencies running. Anyway I'll also try maven because it seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the classpath.  The dependencies are added to your build path which allows your code to compile but not to your classpath which is where you need them for your code to run.

As Daniel said

> Go to the "Run Configurations" dialog (Run -> Run Configurations) for the class you are executing and click on "Dependencies" there

Also Daniel's suggestion

> Do yourself a favor and set up your project using Maven. (Configure --> add Maven nature.). You can add dependencies in your pom.xml file and Eclipse/Maven takes care of all the classpath stuff. (You would only need to add the oshi dependency, and its own pom tells Maven what other dependencies to get.). Your future self will thank you a million times over

is very apt